# How to get IEEE promotion code

Tags: ieee

I want to join IEEE community by purchasing IEEE student membership. On the check-out page there is a field for entering promotion code which offers discount. How can I receive a promotion code?

Comment: **Moderator’s Notice:** Please do not try to share any codes here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set of promotion codes often would be dedicated to the people, who are members of IEEE and has been promoted to the upper membership level, typically. Those members are supposed to present those codes to the other people, willing to become new members of IEEE. For example, an IEEE Member will receive a couple of promotion codes, as he/she has been promoted to IEEE Senior Member. He/She could grant those codes, as gift, to the others (especially his/her students), to be considered for the membership discount.

All in all, you better find any recently-promoted guy around yourself and if any, he/she would, probably, be able to provide you a promotion code, as you need.

Comment: Do you have any source to indicate that these codes are actually more related to promotion of member rank than a "promo code" on any other internet site is?  Because the link you gave in a comment shows the exact opposite of your answer.

Comment: That's according to my own experience to get one of them from my supervisor, had who been promoted to Senior level